# How to register APID with Urban Airship in MonoDroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, urbanairship.com

I am looking to add push notifications to an app currently in development, The android app has been built using MonoDroid and we are using Urban Airship for push notifications.

Are there any Urban Airship libraries for use with MonoDroid or does Urban Airship have a REST API that can be used to register an APID? We used the iOS REST API (https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Server%3A+iOS+Push+API) to register a device token for the iOS version of the app.

Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a mono for android library on github at [UrbanAirship-Android](https://github.com/bartsipes/UrbanAirship-Android).

Comment: Was just updated for 2.1.2 as well. Unfortunately I can't get any APID's back from the server...